# React Native project do not have index.ios.js or index.android.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi I am newbie for React Native.
I followed below link to build my first project but found there is no index.ios.js or index.android.js for me to edit:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Only App.js is created,
May I know how can I edit for ios and android separately?
Thanks!

Comment: which command you are firing for creating react native project?

Comment: create-react-native-app AwesomeProject

Comment: use this command 
react-native init YourProjectName

Comment: but use this command I seems cannot use expo for app preview?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Firstly make sure that you are done with the downloads of**:

- Java Sdk
- Android Studio
- Xcode (in case of OSX)
- HomeBrew (in case of OSX to install node)
- Node/NPM (Node runs Javascript outside the browser. NPM is used for 
  installing and managing Dependencies. Node and NPM come together)

Those are some essential installs that you will need in your Project

For windows/OSX you need to run the following commands in your command
prompt/command line:

This is the important part for running a react native project:

- **npm install -g react-native-cli**

Then you can use this cli to start a new project like this:

- **react-native init projectname**

after following these steps you can get the index.android.js file
and the index.ios.js file where you can code/ edit for ios/android
seperately

App.js or any other file can be created by us while index.android.js and
index.ios.js file comes by default

**But now we have index.js file** instead of index.android.js and
index.ios.js **and an  App.js file**, so you can write your codes in App.js and register the file in index.js to make it work on both ios and android

so your app registers only once that is in index.js earlier we need to copy paste the same registering code in both index.ios.js and index.android.js to make it work on android and ios that was like duplication of the same code so they must have deprecated that

Comment: thanks for the reply, may I know if this method can use expo for preview the application? if yes, how to implement expo to the project? thanks

Comment: yes the same applies for expo 
after you finish all the above steps install expo xde then create a new project in expo xde
open the project in an editor and you can write codes in App.js
 and run it on devices via expo

Comment: may i know react-native init project name and create new project in expo are the same folder?

Comment: you need to do either ways 
like if u are trying to develop an app via expo then u should create an expo project

Comment: I have done all the above mentioned steps, still I don't find them in my project. Also, my project runs perfectly in Android Emulator. Is both the files index.android.js and index.ios.js are removed from react-native?

Comment: @Adarsh Sreeram, Same problem here. I just began learning react-native yesterday, I made my first hello react project which contained both the mentioned files but when I am creating a new project now, both the files are not there yet its running on the emulator. What can be the reason?

Comment: I think the index.android.js and index.ios.js is deprecated and replaced with index.js 

well what happens is at run time the first file that gets loaded is the index.js file 

so your app registers only once that is in index.js earlier we need to copy paste the same registering code in both index.ios.js and index.android.js to make it work on android and ios  that was like repeating the code

Comment: Hi, I know this thread is long ago. I just started react native this month. I already setup everything and when I created app `react-native init nameproject` then I checked to file structure and there is no `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` but only have `index.js`. I think this maybe for new version of react native

Answer (score 53):

For the latest version of React native(0.49.3), it seems that the "index.android.js" and "index.ios.js" separate entry routes are no longer supported. The developer documentation suggests we use the App.js and only change parts of platform specific code by importing {Platform} from react-native package if needed.

[Developer documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#modifying-your-app)

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/165140/react-native-tutorial-building-ios-android-apps-javascript

Was following the above article which was written very recently and was quite confused. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this info! Because of this comment, I was able to search for additional information which helped as well. This other thread was useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510221/advantages-of-having-index-ios-js-instead-of-just-index-js

Answer (score 1):

According to this article, even in React Native 0.60 those platform specific file extensions are still supported.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code#platform-specific-extensions

Answer (score 1):

Henceforth and with coming versions of React Native development platform, the index.ios.js and index.android.js files are no longer available for development purposes. There is now a single file that one can use to carry out all development activities- the App.js in relation with the index.js file (just like the normal React.js) way of doing things.

#### STEPS ON MAC OS

1. Ensure that you set all development packages using the MAC OS terminal
2. Download and install the latest [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) package
3. Run `npm --version` to confirm the installation of the latest `Node.js` version
4. Still, on your terminal, install HomeBrew using

   ```
   /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```
5. Then install watchman using`brew install watchman`
6. Finally, install React-Native using

   ```
   npm install -g react-native-cli
   ```

Then you can start building your react native app using

```
react-native init appName
```

Editing the `App.js` and the `index.js` files are what you'll do in most cases when developing. You might as well download some other dependencies as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually create a javascript file and name it  **index.android.js** or **index.ios.js**. The commands written in these files can be the same as of **index.js** file or even be platform-specific.