# React native index.ios.js and index.android.js

Tags: react-native

Am new to react native, I set up the react native in ubuntu operating system and i created the app using below command

react-native init project_name

But only app.js and index.js files are generated with node modules, I didn't get the index.ios.js and index.android.js files generated automatically.?

Do i need to add these index.ios.js and index.android.js files manually or it has to generate automatically.?

Comment: Refer this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455202/react-native-project-do-not-have-index-ios-js-or-index-android-js/46461578#46461578](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455202/react-native-project-do-not-have-index-ios-js-or-index-android-js/46461578#46461578)

Comment: @nadeshoki thank you

Comment: Can you show your package.json file of your react-native?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native project, index.ios.js or index.android.js not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591682/react-native-project-index-ios-js-or-index-android-js-not-generated)

Answer (score 0):

Related to react-native version 0.49 which joins both index.ios.js and index.android.js to index.js. Hope this helps!